# python requests POST error, session issue?

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to mimic the following browser actions via python's `requests`:

1. Land on https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/to_nlp_start
2. Click "More search options"
3. Click checkbox "Also find historicised data" (corresponds to POST param: `isHistorical: true`)
4. Click button "Search net short positions"
5. Click button "Als CSV herunterladen" to download csv file

This is the code I have to simulate this:

```
import requests
import re

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/to_nlp_start", verify=False, allow_redirects=True)

matches = re.search(
        r'form class="search-form" id=".*" method="post" action="\.(?P<appendtxt>.*)"',
        r.text
    )
request_url = f"https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en{matches.group('appendtxt')}"
sr = session.post(request_url, data={'isHistorical': 'true', 'nlp-search-button': 'Search net short positions'}, allow_redirects=True)
```

However, even though `sr` gives me a status_code 200, it's really an error when I check `sr.url`, which shows `https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/error-404?9`

Digging a bit deeper, I noticed that `request_url` above resolves to something like

```
https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp;wwwsid=EFEB15CD4ADC8932A91BA88B561A50E9.web07-pub?0-1.-nlp~filter~form~panel-form
```

but when I check the request url in Chrome, it's actually

```
https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/nlp?87-1.-nlp~filter~form~panel-form`
```

The `87` here seems to change, suggesting it's some session ID, but when I'm doing this using `requests` it doesn't appear to resolve properly.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script to download the CSV file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en/to_nlp_start'

data = {
    'fulltext': '',
    'positionsinhaber': '',
    'ermittent': '',
    'isin': '',
    'positionVon': '',
    'positionBis': '',
    'datumVon': '',
    'datumBis': '',
    'isHistorical': 'true',
    'nlp-search-button': 'Search+net+short+positions'
}

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    action = soup.find('form', action=lambda t: 'nlp~filter~form~panel-for' in t)['action']
    u = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en' + action.strip('.')    

    soup = BeautifulSoup( s.post(u, data=data, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser' )

    a = soup.select_one('a[title="Download as CSV"]')['href']
    a = 'https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/pub/en' + a.strip('.')    

    print( s.get(a, headers=headers).content.decode('utf-8-sig') )
```

Prints:

```
"Positionsinhaber","Emittent","ISIN","Position","Datum"
"Citadel Advisors LLC","LEONI AG","DE0005408884","0,62","2020-08-21"
"AQR Capital Management, LLC","Evotec SE","DE0005664809","1,10","2020-08-21"
"BlackRock Investment Management (UK) Limited","thyssenkrupp AG","DE0007500001","1,50","2020-08-21"
"BlackRock Investment Management (UK) Limited","Deutsche Lufthansa Aktiengesellschaft","DE0008232125","0,75","2020-08-21"
"Citadel Europe LLP","TAG Immobilien AG","DE0008303504","0,70","2020-08-21"
"Davidson Kempner European Partners, LLP","TAG Immobilien AG","DE0008303504","0,36","2020-08-21"
"Maplelane Capital, LLC","VARTA AKTIENGESELLSCHAFT","DE000A0TGJ55","1,15","2020-08-21"


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check https://www.bundesanzeiger.de/robots.txt, this website does not like to be indexed. The website could be denying access to the default user agent used by bots. This might help : [Python requests vs. robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891446/python-requests-vs-robots-txt)

Comment: I tried adding:

    `HEADERS = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
                      " Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Host": 'www.bundesanzeiger.de'
    }  `

and then `s.headers.update(HEADERS)`, but still get the same issue.